# How to deploy a stand-alone application as an npm module?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Is there a way to load an npm module as the main application?

I'm used to using git to load some application like:

```
git clone https://github.com/me/myapp.git
cd myapp
npm install
```

`npm install` always puts dependency modules under the `node_modules` path.

How would I deploy a stand-alone application as a node module?

Is there something equivalent to:

```
npm install myapp
cd myapp
npm start
```

Comment: Dockerize your node app

Comment: A docker container would make it difficult for a user to configure and add additional modules to the app.

Answer (score 3):

Create a github new project let say **myapp**

**Clone the project**

```
git clone  https://github.com/me/myapp.git
```

Generate the `package.json`
Update the your code logic 
     let create file index.js add some code

```
module.exports = (name) =>name;
```

Create a npm account
  https://www.npmjs.com/signup

**login npm**

go to the terminal type below the command

```
npm login
```

**Publish the npm package**

```
npm publish  https://github.com/me/myapp.git
```

**Install the package**

```
 npm install myapp
```

**Start import the the module**

```
  let name =require('myapp')
  console.log(name("hello world"));
```